# Suppressing Pandas dataframe plot output

Tags: python, pandas

I am plotting a dataframe:

```
        ax = df.plot()
        fig = ax.get_figure()
        fig.savefig("{}/{}ts.png".format(IMGPATH, series[pfxlen:]))
```

It works fine.  But, on the console, I get:

```
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py:2542: UserWarning: Attempting to set identical left==right results in singular transformations; automatically expanding. left=736249.924955, right=736249.924955 + 'left=%s, right=%s') % (left, right))
```

Basic searching hasn't showed me how to solve this error.  So, I want to suppress these errors, since they garbage up the console.  How can I do this?

Comment: Are you only plotting one datapoint or a series of data with the same x value?

Comment: @wflynny - this is a time series read from InfluxDB to the dataframe.  It contains time and a measurement (float).

Comment: So I take it that you are plotting a single datapoint.  Somewhere, either in your code or within `df.plot()`, you are calling `ax.set_xlim(736249.924955, 736249.924955)` and that's what matplotlib is complaining about.

Comment: @wflynny - Indeed.  Since df.plot() is out of my control, I'd like to suppress the error messages to terminal, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those aren't errors, but warnings. If you aren't concerned by those and just want to silence them, it's as simple as:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Additionally, pandas and other libraries may trigger NumPY floating-point errors. If you encounter those, you have to silence them as well:

```
import numpy as np
np.seterr('ignore')
```